# C++ multiple for loop bottleneck

Tags: c++

my C++ program has encountered a bottleneck. There is a function to cut the rgb32 image. Look at the code:

```
BOOL Convert2MultiImage(BYTE *p32Img, BYTE** p24Img, int dxSize32, int  dySize32, int row, int vertical)
{

BYTE *pTemp;
BYTE** ptr = new BYTE*[row * vertical];

pTemp = p32Img;

for (int num = 0; num < row * vertical; num++)
{
    ptr[num] = p24Img[num];
}

int displayWidth = dxSize32 * vertical;
int width4 = displayWidth * 4;
int width4_y = displayWidth * dySize32 * 4;
int x_4 = dxSize32 * 4;

int p = 0;
int seq = 0;

int  i, j;

for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
{
    for (int v = 0; v < vertical; v++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < dySize32; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < dxSize32; i++)
            {
                p = (displayWidth * j + i + r * displayWidth * dySize32 + v * dxSize32) * 4;

                *(ptr[seq]++) = pTemp[p];
                *(ptr[seq]++) = pTemp[p + 1];
                *(ptr[seq]++) = pTemp[p + 2];

            }
        }
        seq++; 
    }
}

delete[] ptr;
ptr = NULL;

return true;
}
```

The parameter dxSize32 = 1920, dySize32 = 1080, row=4, vertical=4; the function means to cut from 8K image into 16 1080P images.

this code takes about 300ms, and I need about 30ms, my The computer CPU is I5-6400 dual core. Can I use some hardware to process this code to reduce the time spent?

NOW I used opencv, very good, now it takes about 30ms.

```
void COpencvCutImg::BGR32_Cut_MultiBGR24(BYTE* source, BYTE** target, int   width, int height, int row, int vertical)
{
Mat matSource = Mat(width, height, CV_8UC4, source);

int height1 = matSource.rows;
int width1 = matSource.cols;

int ceil_height = height1 / row;
int ceil_width = width1 / vertical;

Mat roi_img;

int seq = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
for (int j = 0; j<vertical; j++){

    Rect rect(j*ceil_width, i*ceil_height, ceil_width, ceil_height);

    roi_img = matSource(rect);

    Mat continuousBGRA(roi_img.size(), CV_8UC3, target[seq]);
    cv::cvtColor(roi_img, continuousBGRA, CV_BGRA2BGR, 3);

    seq++;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you  compiled it with optimiazation? For your CPU architecture (SSE, AVX)? Please note, that SO is not a codereview server, that's what https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for :)

Comment: Executing the operations in e.g. 16  threads for each image, would be an idea. 4-nested for loops are higly ineffecient

Comment: @Korni You're not going to get a factor of 10 gain with threads given your CPU is dual core... the very best you can hope for is double a 100% increase via that route.

Comment: 1.  Turn the optimizer up to the maximum. 2.  Turn the inner loop into a memcpy.  3.  Consider unrolling the j loop eight or 16 times.

Comment: @UKMonkey If it's got two real cores there may be another two "hyperthreading" cores available, but even in the ideal world, that's only x4 and the possible cache interference etc means the world is very far from ideal.

Comment: Concerning code optimization you can do something in an obvious way - move some parts of `p = (displayWidth * j + i + r * displayWidth * dySize32 + v * dxSize32) * 4;` to external loops (e.g. `displayWidth * j` can be calculated out of (before) `i`-loop) or pre-calculated before loops (e.g. `displayWidth * dySize32`)

Comment: You also can consider metaprogramming to unroll the loops easily in compile time

Comment: @VolAnd - won't that part be optimized by compiler if settings are switched on?

Comment: It looks to me like you are moving about 30 megabytes. You need to start thinking about the bandwidth to main memory.

Comment: @donghui - What do you mean by "Can I use some hardware to process this code to reduce the time spent?"? Do you mean more RAM/CPU or L1/L2 cache?

Comment: For this kinf of operation, you could use OpenCV, it is highly optimized for this kind of operations.

Comment: @mfromla Yes, there is no way to optimize by CPU instruction, I remember that the function inside the intel ipp library is very fast, I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: @MartinBonner hyperthreads aren't real cores.  They offer a second pipeline to the same core; which can improve performance - but can also reduce it; situation depending.  For this case, where all the data is in the cache; I don't see how the core can become more efficient.

Comment: @donghui.R You haven't answered the question: "Have you compiled it with optimization?" - Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: There is no guarantee that multiple threads will be more efficient.  Worst case, the threads will be run sequentially on one core (maybe time swapped also).  Best case, the cores need to be scheduled to receive the threads, then monitored for the termination of the threads.  In other words, a lot of overhead for threads.  Also, there may be a bottleneck with data sharing between the multiple cores or threads.  IMHO, loop unrolling or using parallel data instructions would be more efficient.

Comment: Maybe a better technique would be to optimize the function for data cache access.  You can gain a lot of efficiency by reducing the data cache reloading.  Similarly, increasing the ratio of data instructions to branch/jump instructions will increase efficiency.

Comment: @ VolAnd Yes, I modified the code. The running time was about 5% less.

Comment: @ Ricardo Alves，Thank you, I used opencv, very good, now it takes about 40ms.

Comment: @donghui.R you could add your edit as an *answer* instead, if you feel that it answered your question. It is fully acceptable to answer your own questions

Comment: @donghui.R Please post your solution as an answer for this question and accept it, so that it is not marked as unanswered.